# Data Flows from USAID Projects to Missions to Agency Level

Tags: usaidopen

Where can I find information about how data flows from individual USAID-funded projects (typically implemented by contractors) to the USAID Missions and ultimately to Agency-level databases and reports?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, Barbara! Since the release of [White House memorandum M-13-13](https://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/whitehouse.gov/files/omb/memoranda/2013/m-13-13.pdf) and its interpretation for USAID in [ADS 579](https://www.usaid.gov/ads/policy/500/579), USAID-funded projects that generate data are required to submit it directly to the Development Data Library, which is a repository for the Agency's data. From the DDL, researchers within and outside of the Agency can write reports and publications.

Sometimes, projects also share data with missions, but this is an informal process that varies by mission.

Hope this helps! —Robin, USAID Data Services